# Do services run SQL queries?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

I want to create a service which moves a document and renames it based off a table that can be used by a SQL query. I have the same code that uses a button push and does what needs to be done. However, when I run the service, it sees the documents, but then it goes to grab an ID for the document, but it stops at the SQL query and does not continue.

If I take out the SQL calls, it moves the documents and renames them to a generic name I can assign. I want to automate this and use a SQL query.

```
    public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Monitoring the System.", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);

        try
        {
            string dest = @"F:\Temp2\";
            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"F:\Temp\"))
            {
                List<Document> ld = new List<Document>();
                SQLImport si = new SQLImport();

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.ToString());
                ld = si.getDocID();
                int docID = ld[0].DocID;
                int newDocName = docID + 1;
                int accountNumber = 1;
                string docStatus = "New Import";
                string fileName2 = docRetrieval.doc(newDocName.ToString());
                string newdocName = fileName2 + ".pdf";
                string nameChange = file.Replace(fileName, newdocName);
                si.setDocumentInformation(newDocName, accountNumber, dest, docStatus);
                string destFile = Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(nameChange));
                if (!File.Exists(destFile))
                    File.Move(file, destFile);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("The process failed: {0}");
        }
    }
```

SQLImport/Export:

```
    public List<Document> getDocID()
    {

        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(helper.CnnVal("WorkflowConfiguration")))
        {

            var output4 = connection.Query<Document>($"Select DocID From [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[CustomerDoc] ORDER BY DocID DESC").ToList();
            return output4;

        }
    }
```

What is being overlooked?

Comment: If you need the max Id just do a `Select Max(DocID)` instead.  It should be a faster query that way depending on how many rows you have in your table. And you don't need to hydrate into a `Document`, just return whatever the type of `DocID` is.

Comment: Do some logging from the service.  You'll likely find that the connection is failing (depending on what your connection string looks like).  Remember that services run with a separate identity, and generally without a profile loaded.  Have you looked for exceptions in the Event Log?

Comment: I know my connection string looks like this `<add name="WorkflowConfiguration" connectionString="Server=SERVER\INSTANCE;  Database=WorkFlow Creation; Trusted_Connection= Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Comment: `but it stops at the SQL query and does not continue.` How any records are in the table?

Comment: @mjwills There are 31 records right now because I was verifying to see if code was broken. It grabs the information right when I create a winform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing the Logon As from the `Local System` login to an account that has access to the SQL server. Stemming from the answer from @FlyDog57

Thanks for your help!